# WP forntend user Post

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently, I'm developing WordPress site.In that,I have to allow normal users to Login/register.After, they can post posts.After the approval of the admin, the post will be published on the site.Also, concern user wants to view, edit or delete his/her previous posts.

Is any plugin there?

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to use two different plugin.

1) User Front Login / Register :: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/zm-ajax-login-register/

2) User can post from the front end ::
https://wordpress.org/plugins/ppress/

Thanks

Comment: thanks for your reply. does ppress allow users to view/edit/delete his previous post.